# Using from_iter to create BTreeSet in rust

Tags: rust

another basic Rust question: can somebody please give an example of using [from_iter](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) to create [BTreeSet](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/btree_set/struct.BTreeSet.html)?

Presumably, BTreeSet does implement FromIterator trait, but the form that would have been most useful:

```
let triangles = range(1, top).map(|x| x*(x+1)/2);
let bset: BTreeSet<uint> = BTreeSet::from_iter(triangles);
```

Gives error:

```
.../src/main.rs:28:32: 28:51 error: unresolved name `BTreeSet::from_iter`. .../src/main.rs:28
 let bset: BTreeSet<uint> = BTreeSet::from_iter(triangles);
```

OK, this is a trait, so should be an object method:

```
let triangles = range(1, top).map(|x| x*(x+1)/2);
let bset: BTreeSet<uint> = BTreeSet::new();
return bset.from_iter(triangles);
```

but this gives an error:

```
    .../src/main.rs:29:17: 29:37 error: type `collections::btree::set::BTreeSet<uint>` does not implement any method in scope named `from_iter`
.../src/main.rs:29     return bset.from_iter(triangles);
                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.../src/main.rs:29:37: 29:37 note: found defined static methods, maybe a `self` is missing?
.../src/main.rs:29:17: 29:37 note: candidate #1 is defined in the trait `core::iter::FromIterator`
.../src/main.rs:29     return bset.from_iter(triangles);
```

So, what is the right way to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it needs to be qualified with the name of the trait:

```
let bset: BTreeSet<uint> = FromIterator::from_iter(triangles);
```

But I think it's more idiomatic to use .collect():

```
let bset: BTreeSet<uint> = range(1, 10).map(|x| x*(x+1)/2).collect();
```

Comment: I seem to remember having run into this before. The same name lookup issues also happened to me with aliases as well, and both times I was very confused before realizing I had to dig out the type/trait that really declared the method.

Comment: Didn't know collect() can be used like that, definitely the way to go, thanks!